# How to apply date in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, date, typescript

This is my function for todays date:

```
public static todaysDate(month: number): string {
        let day = new Date().getDate();
        let year = new Date().getFullYear();
        return "<span>" + day + ", " + "</span>" + year;
    }
```

and this is for tomorrows date:

```
public static tomorrowsDate(month: number): string {
            let day = new Date().getDate() + 1;
            let year = new Date().getFullYear();
            return "<span>" + day + ", " + "</span>" + year;
        }
```

In my HTML:

```
<ul class="text-left">
                <li><img src="../left.png"/></li>
                <li><span [innerHTML]="date"></span></li>
                <li><img src="../images/right.png"/></li>
            </ul>
```

I'm using `[innerHTML]` to render the HTML `<span></span>` tags.

This is my component:

```
this.date = Date.todaysDate(this.month);
this.dateTomorrow = Date.tomorrowsDate(this.month);
```

How can I apply tomorrows date and yesterdays date on right.png and left.png image clicks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem better for your functions to return a date and to use a pipe in the interpolated string to reformat to the desired date format.

Something like this {{ date | date }}

Here is a plunker with an example: https://plnkr.co/edit/amip8h2pZMxeM7fi7yAZ?p=preview

I used buttons since I didn't have your images, but the code should basically be the same.

```
  <ul class="text-left">
       <li><button (click)="todaysDate(3)">left</button></li>
       <li>{{date | date}}</li>
       <li><button (click)="tomorrowsDate(3)">right</button></li> 
  </ul>
```

And the component functions:

```
export class App {
    name:string;
    date: date;
    constructor() {
       this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
    }

  todaysDate(month: number): void {
    let day = new Date().getDate();
    let year = new Date().getFullYear();
    this.date = new Date(year, month, day);

  }

  tomorrowsDate(month: number): void {
        let day = new Date().getDate() + 1;
        let year = new Date().getFullYear();
        this.date = new Date(year, month, day);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the '3' in your function??

Comment: Your functions both take in a month as a parameter ... so I assumed we needed to pass in the month number?

Comment: If you don't need to pass in a month, then remove the 3 and change the functions to not require a month.

Comment: Oh months are automatically passed in the component :)

Comment: So was the plunker enough to get you started in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind `click` event for each buttons. Inside your click events, update your `date` variable. So your html will be like

```
<ul class="text-left">
    <li><img ng-click="yesterdayDate()" src="../left.png"/></li>
    <li><span>{{date}}</span></li>
    <li><img ng-click="tomorrowDate()"src="../images/right.png"/></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can I bind multiple click events? And this is Angular2, not AngularJS. )

Comment: what do you mean by multiple click events? If it's angular2 please update your question tags